# Disable some facebook app story variations from posting to timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-stream-story

Is there any way to disable some (not all) of the sentences from auto-posting from a Facebook app to a Facebook users profile/timeline?

Ideally I would like just the 'one-to-one' options to be active - the reason for this is that Facebook seems to add activity to the timeline from the past after it has happened, which is useless as no one sees it.

[image: Screenshot of app stories]

Comment: Are you looking for the `no_feed_story` parameter? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/#publish

Comment: Wouldn't that prevent the story from posting entirely? I don't think I want that, I just don't want all of the "one-to-many", "many-to-one" variations enabled